# CSS não funciona quando *ngIf é true

Tags: css, angular

Tenho um *ngFor que roda num array de objetos vindo de um JSON. Numa div filha tenho um *ngIf que verifica se o id do objeto é par ou ímpar como no código abaixo:

**timeline.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of timelineInfo" class="timeline">
    <div *ngIf="entry.id % 2 === 1; else elseBlock">
        <div class="timeline-left">
            <div>
                <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
                <p>{{entry.quote}}</p>
            </div>
            <h1 class="timeline-year">{{entry.year}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-right">
            <img src="{{entry.picture}}" alt="{{entry.title}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <div class="timeline-left">
            <img src="{{entry.picture}}" alt="{{entry.title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-right">
            <h1 class="timeline-year">{{entry.year}}</h1>
            <div>
                <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
                <p>{{entry.quote}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

O objetivo é somente trocar a posição da imagem com a do texto quando mudo de objeto como na figura abaixo:

[layout esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x21Wk.png)

Esse é o css que tentei aplicar:

**timeline.component.css**

```
.timeline { /* Div do for */
    display: flex;
}

.timeline-left, .timeline-right { /* div que abriga os textos/imagem */
    width: 50%;
}
```

Esse é o resultado que tenho:
O CSS funciona corretamente só quando *ngIf é false e o #elseBlock é renderizado.

[resultado obtido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBpcg.png)

O que está errado aqui?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que o ngIf permite os componentes filhos existirem somente quando for true, nesse caso, quando ele for false, os componentes filhos não são renderizados. E ai quebra seu app. Sugiro mudar a estratégia de forma que não precise usar o ngIf

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

O seu código tá certo, porém o HTML que o Angular renderiza nesse caso é um pouco diferente do que o que você está esperando.

A sua diretiva estrutural *ngIf se encontra dentro de uma tag "div", logo o Angular irá repetir essa tag todas as vezes quando renderizar. Cada tag "div" gerada não estará estilizada com "display: flex" por não ter a classe "timeline" (o pai dela estará, a div com a diretiva *ngFor). Logo os filhos dessa div também não herdarão o estilo display flex e se comportarão como div normais, quebrando linha a cada nova tag.

Isso não ocorre com o ng-template pois a tag ng-template nunca é renderizada (ela é apenas um placeholder), seus filhos são renderizados diretamente.

Para resolver seu problema vc pode utilizar outra tag do Angular que também não é renderizada e aceita diretivas (ng-container) ou estilizar a sua div do *ngIf para também ter o estilo display:flex;

Exemplo com ng-container:

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of timelineInfo" class="timeline">
  <ng-container *ngIf="entry.id % 2 === 1; else elseBlock">
    <div class="timeline-left">
      <div>
        <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ entry.quote }}</p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="timeline-year">{{ entry.year }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-right">
      <img
        style="max-width: 200px"
        src="{{ entry.picture }}"
        alt="{{ entry.title }}"
      />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <div class="timeline-left">
      <img
        style="max-width: 200px"
        src="{{ entry.picture }}"
        alt="{{ entry.title }}"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-right">
      <h1 class="timeline-year">{{ entry.year }}</h1>
      <div>
        <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ entry.quote }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Você pode conferir esse exemplo na prática nesse StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kyx8zz

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).